# Dash: "Lock" Button while triggered function is executed

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have following problem:
In my Plotly Dash application, there is a function triggered by a button, which can take up to a 30 seconds until it's execution is finished.

My problem now is, that the function can be triggered a second time by a button click while still be executed the first time.

As an example:

```
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import dash_html_components as html
import time

app = dash.Dash()


app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H2('Imports'),
    html.Button('Button', id='button'),
    html.H3(id='button-clicks'),
])


@app.callback(
    Output('button-clicks', 'children'),
    [Input('button', 'n_clicks')]
)
def import_data(n_clicks):
    if n_clicks:
        for t in range(0, 10):
            print(t)
            time.sleep(1)
    return 'Button has been clicked {} times'.format(n_clicks)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

when I'm clicking my button, the output will be as desired:
0
1
2
3
4

but when I'm clicking the button twice within for example 2 seconds, the output will be: 0
1
2
0
3
1
4
2
3
4, because it is executing my import_data function twice in parallel.

Is there any way to prevent this parallel execution (for example with locking the button)?

THX & BR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure which version of Flask you are using, but it seems like in your case `threaded` parameter is enabled by default. When `threaded` parameter is enabled Flask handles the requests concurrently.

Try disabling it,

`app.run_server(debug=True, threaded=false)`